# Next js jQuery with java script constructor functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, next.js

I have this flow of files.

[image]

In container.jsx component I import the udf-compatible-datafeed.js file like this

```js
_createChart(){
 const UDFCompatibleDatafeed = (await import("./datafeeds/udf/src/udf-compatible-datafeed")).default;
}
```

This import failed and this gives me an error

> Error: jQuery was not found. Please ensure jQuery is referenced before
> the SignalR client JavaScript file.

The error comes from this **data-pluse-provider** file

```js
import { logMessage, } from './helpers';
import $ from 'jquery';

require('signalr');
window.jQuery = $;

const DataPulseProvider = function(){};

export {DataPulseProvider}
```

This file requires jQuery. I think due to SSR reasons. `window` object may not be defined here.
I can't use nextjs dynamic imports here as well. Because this is a JavaScript file, not a jsx component.

But from the index.jsx component I import the component with next js dynamics and for the ContainerPage as well. But the error is still there.

How can I fix this with next.js?
Any help!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you load jQuery? Does view-source show a link to the jQuery library?

Comment: Have you tried calling `window.jQuery = $;` _before_ you call  `require('signalr');`?